# PHP foreach loop MySQL Array Navigation

Tags: php, arrays

i've an array looks like this:

```
$primary_nav = array(
    array(
        'name'  => 'Dashboard',
        'url'   => 'index.php',
        'icon'  => 'gi gi-stopwatch'
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'eCommerce',
        'icon'  => 'gi gi-shopping_cart',
        'sub'   => array(
            array(
                'name'  => 'Dashboard',
                'url'   => 'page_ecom_dashboard.php'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'Design Kit',
        'opt'   => '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Quick Settings"><i class="gi gi-settings"></i></a>',
        'url'   => 'header'
    )
);
```

It's working with no errors but here comes now my problem. I wanna add this settings into the database to get not a big .php file for the navigation parts.

My Code looks like this right now:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM navigation");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach ($results as $result){
        $primary_nav = array(
            array(
                'name'  => $result->name,
                'url'   => $result->url,
                'icon'  => $result->icon
            )
        );
    }
}
```

MySQL print_r

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Dashboard [url] => index.php [icon] => gi gi-stopwatch ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Test [url] => test.php [icon] => gi gi-shopping_cart ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Test1 [url] => test23.php [icon] => gi gi-shopping_cart ) )
```

The problem i've is, I just get only Test1 into the navigation, the other 2 are just skipped. If I add a new one Test1 will be also skipped and the new one will be only added into the navigation. So it will be always just one link in the navigation.
How I can fix this to get all links into the navigation?

Comment: `$primary_nav` is replaced on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$primary_nav` is replaced at each iteration of the loop. You could push the new array on `$primary_nav` using the `[]=` operator :

```
$primary_nav = [];
foreach ($results as $result){
    $primary_nav[] = array(
        'name'  => $result->name,
        'url'   => $result->url,
        'icon'  => $result->icon
    );
}
```

Comment: To be clear, `[]=` is not "an" operator.